# How to use the free function on int* pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

This is my code:

```
int size;
int *p1;
scanf("%d",&size);
p1 =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size-1));         
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d",&p1[i]);
free(p1);
```

The program runs perfectly until the last line - the free function.
when it gets to it, i get a huge error window something like " HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED".

i know that free function should get a void pointer, but mine is int.
how can i free it?

thanks!

Comment: And never cast the return of `malloc()` !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are scanning in one more number than you have allocated space for

```
p1 =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size-1));         
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
```

that causes the corruption, `malloc` `size * sizeof *p1` bytes.

The call to `free` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
p1 =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size-1));
```

should be

```
p1 =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size));
```

You allocated memory for *size-1* number of integers but you want to read *size* number of them